# How to Vibrate when the app is in the background or the screen off? Cordova 9 Android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

How can I cause my app to vibrate when the app is in the background or the screen is off?

I'm currently using `navigator.vibrate(5000)` but it stops when I turn off the screen.

Any ideas?

My only target is Android users.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby